Share Python object between blocks in Simulink
I have created a class in Python. In my application this class is a kind of lookup table.
Here is a sample class to illustrate the topic :
class ExampleClass:

    def __init__(self, var1):
        self.prop1 = var1

    def get_property(self):
        return self.prop1

Matlab offers the ability to call Python modules directly within the Matlab environment (see Matlab docs)
One calls Python like :
>>> py.importlib.import_module("ExampleClass")
>>> x = py.ExampleClass.ExampleClass(1)
>>> x.get_property()
ans =

     1

What I would like to do is to make x available in Simulink m-function blocks in order to call get_property() from all the m-function blocks. Note that the creation of x is computationally expensive, therefore I want to load it in the workspace once when initializing the simulation.
What I tried so far :
I tried passing my ExampleClass to the m-functions via a mask parameter, but I get an error :
Error:Expression 'object name' for type of data 'x' did not evaluate to a valid type.
Which is understandable because Simulink does not allow to use datatypes other than int, double and other standard data types.
Is there a way around to be able to call x.get_property()from my m-functions ?

I was not able to get any work around for the above problem. Some suggesting use of matlab system objects. i directly went for using evalin() but somehow code generation was complaining about their usage within the scope of block.

Please see this links if it helps for you: https://in.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/516499-passing-a-rigidbodytree-object-as-a-parameter-in-simulink-matlab-function-block

@AkhilNandan thanks for the insights, I have been able to use evalin but with no luck in terms of performance. See the answer I wrote summarising the procedure.
I will test the link you provided !

Good new! I think a similar workaround is given in the link, but this exercise is worth a try.

I updated the following answer. Yes using Matlab System blocks seems pretty close to my first try.

How did you bring the python object into the system object. When I read the documentation it was given that custom objects are supported but I was not able to perform it. It would be nice if you could add that solution too.

Just added the details

Efficient access to python variables
To date, there is no efficient way to access those variables. For other ways to access them, see below.
Using coder.extrinsic and evalin

Note : This workaround works so I share it here but the performance is not satisfactory due to the evalin and coder.extrinsic calls.

It is possible to use objects within the base workspace from a Simulink m-function block with the following functions:
Object creation in the base workspace
>>> py.importlib.import_module("ExampleClass")
>>> x = py.ExampleClass.ExampleClass(1)

In the Simulink m-function block :
function out = fcn()
    coder.extrinsic('get_property_in_matlab') % goes outside of Simulink
    out = 0; % Initialize output type for Simulink
    out = get_property_in_matlab();
end

In Matlab we define a function to call x
function [res] = get_property_in_matlab()
    x_in_matlab = evalin('base', 'x'); % Get the object from base workspace
    res = x_in_matlab.get_property(); % Use the get property method
end

This workaround works but the penalty of using coder.extrinsic and evalin renders this solution unusable performance-wise in my case.
Using a Matlab System block
See documentation.
This yields the same performance as previous try with coder.extrinsic and evalin.
Create a Simulink object : New --> System Object --> Simulink Extension
Then create a property for the object
 % Public, tunable properties
    properties
        ex_class_obj   
    end

In the constructor add the object value :
methods
        % Constructor
        function obj = example_class_caller(varargin)
            % Support name-value pair arguments when constructing object
            setProperties(obj,nargin,varargin{:})
            obj.ex_class_obj = evalin('base', 'x');    
        end
    end
...

Make sure to choose Interpreted execution.
Finally perform your computation in stepImpl:
        function y = stepImpl(obj)
            % Implement algorithm. Calculate y as a function of input u and
            % discrete states.
            
            y= obj.ex_class_obj.get_property();
        end


Thanks for sharing, this looks excellent, I had trouble imagining how to bring the class object as a property within Matlab system class.
